# Bring back Month and Year as new fields through Odata Feed

Tags: powerbi, odata

I'm using the Odata Feed option in Power Bi to bring back data from an API connection.
The source table has a field which is in Date/Time format and has hourly records.
I don't want to bring back every single line as there is a lot of data, so was hoping to aggregate the data while getting it from the Source.
I found a similar query here and tried to replicate it but keep getting an error.

OData.Feed(https://......../OData/PositionPeriods?$apply=filter(PositionId eq 93 and CalendarYear ge 2023) &$compute(year(StartLocal) as y, month(StartLocal) as m)/groupby((EntityName,y,m),aggregate(Volume with sum as MonthlyVolume)), null, [Implementation="2.0"])

StartLocal is the date/Time field in the source.

The error I'm getting is:

{"ErrorCode":"-2146233088","Message":"Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.","Target":null,"Details":null,"InnerError":null,"InstanceAnnotations":[],"TypeAnnotation":null}

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

I would like to see the output being an aggregated table with EntityName, y, m and MonthlyVolume.